# Elasticsearch Sort By Length Of Text

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, kibana

I'm using elasticsearch 7.13 and code on kibana

**This is my mapping**

```
{
   "full_text" : {
      "properties" : {
          "title" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fielddata" : true
          },
      }
   }
}
```

**This is my data**

```
"full_text" : [
  {
    "title" : "Pkd chuyên cho thuê kingdom 101 1pn đến 3pn giá rẻ nhất thị trường chỉ 11 triệu/căn. lh 0919504***"
  }
]
```

**This is my code to sort by length of full_text.title**

```
"sort": {
   "_script": {
      "type": "number",
      "order": "desc",
      "script": {
         "lang": "painless",
         "source": "doc['full_text.title'].value.length()"
       }
   }
}
```

**So why sort result return only 7?**

```
"_source" : {
     "full_text" : [
        {
           "title" : "Pkd chuyên cho thuê kingdom 101 1pn đến 3pn giá rẻ nhất thị trường chỉ 11 triệu/căn. lh 0919504***"
        }
     ]
 },
 "sort": [
     7.0
 ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because doc['full_text.title'] will split "title" into array, you need to join that array to string.
Try this:

```
"source": "int length = String.join(' ',doc['full_text.title']).length(); return length;"
```